# Problem adding a pause/play to responsive slider / carousel. JS CSS HTML No bootstrap or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning to code and have hit a problem on my second slider.

I've aded manual controls to the the second slider with success but I'm really having trouble adding a play/pause button using only JS CSS and HTML. I've managed to add a play pause and some javascript and CSS but it will not wok using pauseSlideshow() and playSlideshow().

I've watched many tutorials over the past week and I can't figure out what my code isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is some of my code:

NB I have excluded the code for the first slider in the webpage as I'm focusing on the second one for the play pause.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat:700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <title>GT</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Main Title Web page start  -->
    <header>
      <h1 class="banner">G-T</h1>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" />
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Image Carousel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
      <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </header>


      Thanks for taking the time to stop by. Watch my journey as I learn to code
      code.

    <!-- Image Carousel with the play pause issue -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/photo-of-a-fish-on-corals-1522160.jpg" alt="Splash" style="width: 100%;" />


      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/photo-of-a-turtle-underwater-847393 (1).jpg" alt="diving" style="width: 100%;"/>


      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/fish-in-water_opt.jpg" alt="Yellow and blue tang fish" style="width: 100%;" />


      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      <a type="button" id="pause">&#x23F8;</a>



    </div>
    <br />

    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>


<script>

var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
// Manual control 
function currentSlide(no) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex = no;
  slides[no - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  if (newslideIndex < 4 && newslideIndex > 0) {
    currentSlide(newslideIndex);
  }
}
// Pause

var playing = true;

var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");

function pauseSlideshow() {
  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
  pauseButton.innerHTML = "&#9656;";
  playing = false;
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function playSlideshow() {
  pauseButton.innerHTML = "&#x23F8;";
  playing = true;
  interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
}

pauseButton.onclick = function () {
  if (playing) {
    pauseSlideshow();
  } else {
    playSlideshow();
  }
};

</script>
```

Comment: plusSlide() function is invoked successfully and the slides go forward and backward on buttons click, without an error in the browser developer tools ... where is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. The problem is with the play/pause button not functioning. IE pauseSlideshow() and playSlideshow()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. Typically a good place to start when something is not working in javascript is using the Inspect Element option within your browser and taking a look if there are any errors within the console. The first thing I noticed when doing this is that there was an error in the console when clicking the play button:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: interval

Referenced within the `pauseSlideshow()` method. It doesn't appear that interval is declared outside of the `playSlideshow()` method so it's inaccessible within the `pauseSlideshow()` method. Including the `var interval` declaration resolves this issue.

When the page first loads you're calling the `showSlides()` method, but this is never setting the interval (which you are desiring to clear when calling the `pauseSlideshow()` method), so I would recommend adding a call `playSlideshow()` as well (to start the interval) -- as a result of the we're using the pauseButton within `playSlideshow()` so we'll want to define that first as well.

The other issue I located is that you're recalling `setTimeout(showSlides, 5000)` at the end of your `showSlides()` method. This causes multiple calls to showSlides when it's invoked from the play button -- causing additional confusion when trying to pause it. Now that we're calling `playSlideshow()` to start the interval after  `showSlides()` when the page first displays, we don't need this additional `setTimeout(showSlides, 5000)` at the end of the `showSlides()` method. It would be ideal to not have to explicitly call `showSlides()` first, but unfortunately `setInterval` isn't the cleanest and delays when first starting without an explicit function call first.

I've included the modified code below:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var interval;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");

showSlides();
playSlideshow();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
// Manual control 
function currentSlide(no) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex = no;
  slides[no - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  if (newslideIndex < 4 && newslideIndex > 0) {
    currentSlide(newslideIndex);
  }
}
// Pause

var playing = true;

function pauseSlideshow() {
  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
  pauseButton.innerHTML = "&#9656;";
  playing = false;
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function playSlideshow() {
  pauseButton.innerHTML = "&#x23F8;";
  playing = true;
  interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
}

pauseButton.onclick = function () {
  if (playing) {
    pauseSlideshow();
  } else {
    playSlideshow();
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat:700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <title>GT</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Main Title Web page start  -->
    <header>
      <h1 class="banner">G-T</h1>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" />
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Image Carousel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
      <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </header>


      Thanks for taking the time to stop by. Watch my journey as I learn to code
      code.

    <!-- Image Carousel with the play pause issue -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/photo-of-a-fish-on-corals-1522160.jpg" alt="Splash" style="width: 100%;" />


      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/photo-of-a-turtle-underwater-847393 (1).jpg" alt="diving" style="width: 100%;"/>


      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/fish-in-water_opt.jpg" alt="Yellow and blue tang fish" style="width: 100%;" />


      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      <a type="button" id="pause">&#x23F8;</a>



    </div>
    <br />

    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```